# How to return compile-constant string literal with C++ constexpr function

Tags: c++, visual-c++, constexpr, compile-time

I have a `constexpr` function and I'm trying to strip the file name from the `__FILE__` macro, that is, remove everything but the path. I sketched up this basic function to do so, and I made it `constexpr` in hopes that the compiler can deduce the result and just place that calculated result as a string in the final binary. The function isn't perfect, just a simple mock-up.

```
constexpr const char* const get_filename()
{
    auto file{ __FILE__ };
    auto count{ sizeof(__FILE__) - 2 };

    while (file[count - 1] != '\\')
        --count;

    return &file[count];
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << get_filename() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that this is not being evaluated at compile time (build: MSVC x64 Release Maximum Speed optimization). I'm assuming this is because of returning a pointer to something inside a constant string in the binary, which is essentially what the function is doing. However, what I want the compiler to do is parse the `get_filename` function and somehow return the string literal `"main.cpp"`, for example, instead of returning a pointer of that substring. Essentially, I want this to compile down so that the final binary just has `main.cpp` in it, and nothing else part of the `__FILE__` macro. Is this possible?

Comment: Yeah, cause I was hoping the compiler would see that my pointer in the array is just another string so it would hardcode the resultant string in the final binary. Is that not possible?

Comment: What compiler error do you get

Comment: The problem is `constexpr` is not what you think it is, you need to specify `constexpr auto evaluated = get_filename();` to make it evaluated at compile time, you could use the `consteval` which was introduced in C++20 to force it to be evaluated at compile time. [Test on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/q7cPdajTd)

Comment: `return &__FILE__[count];` should be the same thing, right? Either way, that builds and produces the same output as my initial example.

Comment: By output I mean the final binary still has the full string, ex, `"C:\Users...\source.cpp"` @thedemons the compiler explorer output still has the full string in the asm listing, and I tried to compile using msvc and it complains, for some reason, `call to immediate function is not a constant expression` (with C++ 20)

Comment: @ArushAgarampur it still has the full string because you return the pointer to the `__FILE__` and not creating a new array

Comment: in C++20 just use [std::source_location](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location)

Comment: problem is `std::source_location` has the full path embedded in the compiled binary, which is what I'm trying to avoid. @thedemons I see, I'm assuming you mean copying `__FILE__` into an array then messing with that will remove the constants?

Comment: @Peter it is returning a pointer into `__FILE__` which is a global constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you don't want the full `__FILE__` path in the final binary, we must copy the string to a `std::array`:

```cpp
constexpr auto get_filename()
{
    constexpr std::string_view filePath = __FILE__;
    constexpr auto count = filePath.rfind("\\");

    static_assert(count != std::string::npos);
    
    std::array<char, count> fileName{};
    std::copy(filePath.data() + count + 1, filePath.data() + filePath.size(), fileName.data());

    return fileName;
}
```

And specify `constexpr` when calling the `get_filename` function:

```cpp
constexpr auto fileName = get_filename();
std::cout << fileName.data();
```

Alternatively, since C++20, you could use `consteval` to force it to be evaluated at compile time:

```cpp
consteval auto get_filename();
```

Here's the [test on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/z3Pe8q8dz), it uses `printf` instead of `std::cout` for a shorter asm.

Comment: Awesome, this works perfectly! Can you explain the `consteval` a little more? (Different meanings under the hood?) Like how it is different than using the 2 line approach with `constexpr`?

Comment: `constexpr` hints that the expression *could* be evaluated at compile time, and the variable which holds the return value needs to be declared with `constexpr` in order for this to work, otherwise, it will be evaluated at runtime, constexpr allows the code to compile even if the expression could not be evaluated. `consteval` on the other hand force the expression to be evaluated at compile time and will fail to compile if it couldn't be evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

The currently accepted answer by `thedemons` computes the resulting `std::array`'s count incorrectly. It is computing the count of characters in `__FILE__` UP TO the last instance of `\\`. This results in more memory being used when the result is stored statically. Which can cause the compiler to NOT use the stack, as shown in `thedemon`'s godbolt.

See [this alternative solution](https://godbolt.org/z/s7P7bx5PG) instead:

```
#include <array>
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

consteval auto get_source_file_name()
{
    // Assumes the target filesystem is the same as the compiler host.
    // Targeting Windows, this is "\\", but targeting Linux from Windows likely means this will include the full __FILE__
    constexpr wchar_t target_filesystem_preferred_separator =
        std::filesystem::path::preferred_separator;

    constexpr std::string_view source_file_path = __FILE__;
    constexpr size_t slash_offset = source_file_path.rfind(target_filesystem_preferred_separator) != std::string::npos
        ? source_file_path.rfind(target_filesystem_preferred_separator)
        // No slash found, use the full string
        : 0;
    // This includes the nil character
    constexpr size_t trimmed_file_path_length =
        source_file_path.length() - slash_offset;

    std::array<char, trimmed_file_path_length> trimmed_file_path{};
    std::copy(source_file_path.data() + (slash_offset + 1), source_file_path.data() + source_file_path.length(), trimmed_file_path.data());

    return trimmed_file_path;
}
static constexpr auto k_source_file_name_char_array = get_source_file_name();

int main()
{
    // std::array is on the stack, at least when compiled with /02
    constexpr auto file_name = get_source_file_name();
    printf("%s\n", file_name.data());

    // std::array is in .rdata
    printf("%s\n", k_source_file_name_char_array.data());

    return 0;
}
```